# History price list for invoices?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, e-commerce

When the customer place an order, the item_id and option_id are stored in the `order_items` table, from there it will generate invoice for the customer. However the price of the item always change every few months and it will affect old invoices information.

What are the solution to fix this problem? I do not want to store the price and item name in the  `order_items` table.

I have read the possible solution is to create `history_prices` table (audit system via trigger or SQL insert query manually via php?), is Audit best solution or is there any other solution?

Can you provide example how do I create `history_prices` table, so when I change the price from `item_options.option_price` - it will be stored into history_prices table?

Right now I have over 200,000 rows in item_options table, do I need to copy the prices into history_prices?

I need an efficient way so the invoices will not be affected from the new price change.

item_options table:

```
mysql> desc item_options;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| option_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| option_name   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| option_price  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

order_items table:

```
mysql> desc order_items;
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| order_items_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| order_id       | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_id        | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| option_id      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following designs out:

[image]

Design 1: Stores a rolling history of changes to the item (New row if anything changes: name, description, price).

Design 2: New row on Price change only.

Alternatively, you can store the price with the order itself.

Comment: Thank you for the designs, which one would you recommend or store the price with the order itself? In regarding to new rows.. how can that be done? For example If I change the item name in the items table, then does that mean I need to add news duplicate rows in the options table? Why did you add StartDate and EndDate fields (There is a ItemPriceID field in OrderItems table)

Comment: If you get a chance, could you please update your design for orderitems tables on my previous question topic. Thanks :) That was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is creating a a column in `order_items` for the price. And that's also the most straightforward.

If you want to create a table with price history for reporting use, that might be fine. But do not give yourself the painful headache of querying the price history just to get some items' price. The price IS an attribute of the item. The price might change due to promotion, discount, special offer, etc.

Comment: There is not many attributes of a product that being often changed so I also think it'd be most straightforward to add them into order_items, i.e. price, discount, size.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of opinion, some will agree that a historical price lookup will be ok, my opinion is that it is not.

The problem with looking up a history of prices and determining the invoice price from that is there is plenty of room for error.  You will have several pieces of logic used to determine the right price, all of which are prone to errors. You could forget to convert the time zone of the invoice, and this could cause it to be on the wrong side of a price change.  You could forget to make any applied discounts or coupon codes date sensitive, etc.  What about ever changing shipping charges?

It is best to store the actual invoice price with the invoice itself.  Disk space is cheap, use the redundancy to sleep better at night.

Comment: It isn't really redundancy.  If your price history table is subject to correction in order to fix errors, then being able to look up an historical price is no guarantee that you're going to get the price as it was when the invoice was first cut.  Also, many things are sold for a price that differs from the price book price due to employee discounts, special promotions and other adjustments.  You can keep a price history table if you think it may come in handy but you should keep the price actually charged on the invoice item table because it is a full-fledged attribute of the invoice item.

Comment: Joel... isn't that exactly what I said?